# RegEx for Only whole numbers, -2 through 100

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression, for whole numbers (no decimals), for a range from -2 - 100. I am struggling with accommodating the negative value.

Comment: what regex you have as of now

Comment: What language are you using?  It may make more sense to have a regex find a likely number, and then have the host language check the value of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably treat the negative numbers as special cases, since you have just two:

```
^(-2|-1|[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)$
```

i.e. -1 OR -2 OR any 1-digit positive integer OR any 2-digit positive integer OR 100.

Comment: This will catch -3 because [0-9] will catch the "3".  You need to anchor the beginning and end to avoid this.

Comment: plus for this as it does not match `00` but could probably shorten it down to `^(?:-[12]|[1-9]?\d|100)$`

Answer (score 2):

You need to special case the negatives and 100.

Try this:

```
^(-[12]|100|[0-9]{1,2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice challenge..

May I be wrong (or not).. anyways, here is my try:

```
/-1(?!\d)|-2(?!\d)|(?<=[^-\d])(100|[0-9]{1,2})(?!\d)/gmi
```

[Live here.](https://regex101.com/r/kB6bK5/2)